# Replace background image with a blob:url

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I'm using a very funky file / image upload provider [GitHub - danialfarid/ng-file-upload: Lightweight Angular directive to upload files with optional FileAPI shim for cross browser support](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)[^]

I am going to use this to allow my customers to choose their own logo and favicon.

They can preview the logo on the page by checking the preview checkbox. This will update the logo and favicon image on the page.
The logo is on $(".main-logo") as a background image:

```
$scope.logoChanged = function () {
  Upload.dataUrl($scope.file, false).then((fileUrl) => { 
//fileUrl: "blob:https://d15461a6.ngrok.io/eb87daf2-8581-4a83-a4d4-35ed19e18903"
    if ($scope.file) {

        const logo = $('.main-logo'); // logo div
        if ($scope.previewImage) { //checkbox model
            const url = 'url("'+fileUrl+'") !important';
            logo.css("background-image", url); 
//url: url("blob:https://d15461a6.ngrok.io/eb87daf2-8581-4a83-a4d4-35ed19e18903") !important
            console.log(logo.css("background-image"))
//logo.css("background-image"): url(/Resources/images/ebLicence.png)
        } else {
            logo.css("background-image", logoBgImage);
        }
    }
  });
}
```

As per the code comments: The image does not change!

I checked that the url is valid by adding it to the element via chrome inspector. No problems there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default cache images so despite the fact that you are replacing your source url the browser won't update the image.

You could just add a random number at the end of your url so that the browser updates it e.g.

`var random = Math.random();
url("'+fileUrl+'?v"+random)`

or just to be safe you can create a new img and replace the one you have at the browser by using a `.replaceWith()`.

Comment: Well that's the great thing about angular.  It will update the cached image.  The issue is that the css is not updating.  I'll try replaceWith().  It won't take long to try ^_^

Comment: Also, the source is changing: url(/Resources/images/ebLicence.png) to url("blob:https://d15461a6.ngrok.io/eb87daf2-8581-4a83-a4d4-35ed19e18903")

Answer (score 0):

Ok - managed to get it to work.

Instead of using css(prop,val) I used attr('style',"prop:val;")

I use this in combo with the replaceWith, but I don't think I'll need to

No idea why .css didn't work

Thanks to Stavros for his attention ^_^